# Was this question deleted? And if yes, why?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, questions, meta

I just now was reading this question - "[the-loop-has-arrived-what-does-the-community-think-about-it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339050/the-loop-has-arrived-what-does-the-community-think-about-it)", then I refreshed the page and it was a 404. What happened to it? Was this question deleted? And if yes, why?

**Edit**: also another question that might have suffered similar symptom [joel-left-se-as-we-know-it-is-dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339074/joel-left-se-as-we-know-it-is-dead), as pointed out in comments.

Comment: seems to be happening to lot of meta posts in SO and SE at least

Comment: I added a bug tag to it.

Comment: We broke SE. Let's face it.

Comment: Same goes for my question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339074/joel-left-se-as-we-know-it-is-dead

Comment: I'm getting "Oops, something bad happened" errors on most Meta questions. I'm surprised this one opened.

Comment: We're investigating an issue with a build.

Comment: @Taryn so it's a bug?

Comment: It's a good thing staff is still reading Meta

Comment: We're investigating an issue with a build....it shouldn't have released YET.

Comment: Is the survey still up?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this affects most meta questions - it's not selective to any one type of question or level of question popularity.

Comment: @Alex, I won't repost [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338010/unplanned-maintenance/338014#comment1124798_338014), but I very much think it.

Comment: @dfhwze, I checked, and it is.

Comment: A build went out to meta that had an unexpected null in certain circumstances. We have a fix and it's building out now.

Comment: @DeanWard status-completed it appears, also builds on friday evening, wasnt there some kind of analogy around that?

Comment: @Luuklag but... it's Monday. Or maybe I slept through the week again?

Comment: @DeanWard Thank you. Cause I got scared there for a second.

Comment: It's not about any particular question. Just had some ten minutes of being unable to access *any* questions on [meta.se]. Tested it, it's not just the "we're unhappy with some things" ones.

Comment: @DeanWard no you havent, my weekend was just too short, or my monday too intense...

Comment: @GalastelsupportsGoFundMonica I tested it too, and I was able to access another question while still not being able to access those two in the post as well as this post of mine, which disappeared for a few minutes back when it was at 19 votes.But I am glad it was just a build problem. Things happen.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This one's on me! The bug is fixed and all built out.

The **tl;dr** is that an array passed into a Razor view that *should never be null*™ turned out to be null (surprise!). We've fixed the code to handle future unexpected nulls and also fixed the source of this null.

Sorry to those of you who've had your day adversely impacted by this!

Comment: Things happen. Thank you very much for feedback!

Answer (score 17):

Comment from [@DeanWard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/267572/dean-ward):

> A build went out to meta that had an unexpected null in certain circumstances. We have a fix and it's building out now.

Answer (score 0):

You were linking to the error page, with “errorpath” in the URL. Here is the original: [The "loop" has arrived, what does the community think about it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339050/the-loop-has-arrived-what-does-the-community-think-about-it)

It worked for me on my iPhone a minute ago.

[image]

Comment: That link does not currently work for me. I'm on Firefox on Ubuntu Linux